# Loading a csv file into spyder(Python 3.6)

Tags: python, spyder

I am currently trying to load a csv file of data into spyder and I just cant figure it out. Also my code below gets a value error stating "could not convert string to float:"

My Code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

data = np.loadtxt('magnet lab.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=2)  

kimberlite = np.array(data[:,0])   

forcekimberlite = np.array(data[:1]) 

plt.scatter(kimberlite,forcekimberlite,s=5,c='red',marker='o')  

plt.xlim(0,5)  

plt.xlabel('distance from center of magnet to kimberlite')  

plt.ylabel('Force') 

plt.title('Kimberlite results')  

plt.show()
```

Comment: show your *.csv

Comment: show your traceback error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As the previous comments state, you have left out important information from your question. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for loading the csv file.

```
data = np.genfromtxt('magnet lab.csv',delimiter=',')
```